# MySQL: Joining two tables, but getting just the first value in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that I am trying to join.

car_make Table:

```
id   |    name   |   color  
---------------------------
12   |   Tayota  |   red
13   |   Ford    |   gray
15   |   Tesla   |   red
17   |   GM      |   blue
```

car_type table:

```
id   |    car_id   |   image_one      |   image_two       |  image_three  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |   12        |   tayota1.jpg    |   tayota2.jpg     |  tayota3.jpg
2    |   17        |   gm1.jpg        |   gm2.jpg         |  gm3.jpg
3    |   12        |   tayota3.jpg    |   tayota4.jpg     |  tayota5.jpg
4    |   13        |   ford1.png      |   ford2.png       |  ford3.png
5    |   13        |   ford4.png      |   ford5.png       |  ford6.png
```

I want to grab and display every row within car_make, and join the first image_one instance for each make.

For example, I would like it to output:

```
Row 1: Tayota, red, tayota1.jpg
Row 2: Ford, gray, ford1.jpg
Row 3: Tesla, red, NULL
Row 4: GM, blue, gm1.jpg
```

How would I structure this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want the equivalent of a `left join` and only want one row, the easiest way might be a correlated subquery:

```
select cm.*,
       (select ct.image_one
        from car_type ct
        where ct.car_id = cm.id
        order by ct.id
        limit 1
       ) as image_one
from car_make cm;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this. Here's one using a sub-query to ensure you're only selecting the 1st car type per car make

```
select * from car_make cm
left join car_type ct on ct.car_id = cm.id
and ct.id = (select min(id) from car_type ct2 where ct2.car_id = ct.car_id)
```